# Calculate wcu for DynamoDB tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have to do a BatchWriteItem on a dynamodb table using AWS lambda. The number of items in the batch is 25. Lets say the average record size for the batch is 1kb. How many WCUs are required for the write to be successful in the first attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) `1 WCU = 1 write up to 1KB`.

Also write batching of 25 items in one operation will counted as 25 `PutItems`, [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Writes):

> DynamoDB processes each item in the batch as an **individual PutItem** or DeleteItem request (updates are not supported). So DynamoDB first rounds up the size of each item to the next 1 KB boundary, and then calculates the total size.

Thus, you need `25 WCU`.

Comment: Yes but I am using only 1 wcu still the requests aint throttling

Comment: @mightyMouse DynamoDB can [burst](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting). So if you do occasionally such writes, DynomoDB will handle it.

Comment: You can also use the `ReturnConsumedCapacity` [Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#DDB-BatchWriteItem-request-ReturnConsumedCapacity) to get more details about how many WCUs are consumed.